# How to set up async processes with Vuex in any specific order

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vuex

### First let's understand the app:

1. The sample app mocks grabbing data from 2 sources: an array of available objects, and an array of objects being used.
2. The app also displays new objects (available ones not being used).
3. Finally, it also allows you to use (register) one of the new objects

### Requirements:

- The app needs to display the list of New objects first
- The app needs to minimize the number of API calls to the bare minimum and only make calls when strictly necessary
- Calls to produce changes in API data (register) should be reactive and display changes in UI immediately

[The code I have implemented](https://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/gzrLWx?editors=1010) meets these 3 requirements. However, I'm really unhappy with this implementation, and I'm sure that's **not** the way the Vuex store is supposed to be used.

For starters, my implementation only works for the specific order in which the components are displayed in the screen:

```
<new name="New" :selected="true"></new>
<available name="Available"></available>
<using name="Using"></using>
```

If I, for example, want to move `<available>` to the last tab, the code will break.

This happens because I haven't been able to simply call `dispatch('getNews')` once and have everything else fall into place, without at the same time duplicating one or to API calls, and thus not meeting the requirements...
I tried using `dispatch('...').then().then()` but I haven't been able to make it work and meet the requirements.

I would greatly appreciate anyone with experience in similar situations with Vuex tell me how they'd do this. 
Bonus if you can do it without adding extra mutations.

Comment: Why wouldn't your "objects" all be in one array, with both 'used' and 'available'?  You'd just have a flag on it saying whether it's in use or not, then filter on the client side for each of those tabs.  Your Vuex store just stores the 5 objects, your mutations send messages to mark one as in use or create another one, and your getters allow you to show only certain ones in the tabs

Comment: Hi @Jeff, that's because they come from different sources and have very different sets of props. Good suggestion though, I like the idea of having a single set of data. I can try to create a new array, mapping the props I need and adding those flags.

Comment: [Here's a reimplementation](https://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/JvRZEx?editors=1010) that uses a type of 'init' action called 'getEverything' and meets the requirements. However, the code is not DRY...
I learned from this experience that I have no choice but to use mutations to keep separate states between client and server.